# Need help creating a simple maths quiz (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm a fairly new programmer and I'm looking for some help with my current task. I'm trying to create a program which generates 2 random numbers and a random operator, then ask the user to type in their answer. I think I've got this part done.

However when I try to get the program to display the correct answer, it simply shows the problem and doesn't answer the question with the correct answer.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Randomize()
    Dim RandomNum As New Random

    Dim Number1 As Integer
    Dim Number2 As Integer
    Dim Operation As Integer
    Dim Output As String
    Dim Answer As String


    Number1 = RandomNum.Next(1, 20)
    Number2 = RandomNum.Next(1, 20)
    Operation = RandomNum.Next(1, 4)


    If (Operation = 1) Then
        Output = " + "
    ElseIf (Operation = 2) Then
        Output = " - "
    ElseIf (Operation = 3) Then
        Output = " * "
    Else
        Output = " / "
    End If


    Console.WriteLine("What is " & Number1 & Output & Number2 & "?")
    Answer = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Your answer is " & Answer)
    Console.WriteLine("The correct answer is " & Number1 & Output & Number2) <------ Here is where the problem is

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add something that calculates the right answer:

```
Dim correctAnswer as Single
```

and then change to the following:

```
If (Operation = 1) Then
    Output = " + "
    correctAnswer = Number1 + Number2
ElseIf (Operation = 2) Then
    Output = " - "
    correctAnswer = Number1 - Number2
ElseIf (Operation = 3) Then
    Output = " * "
    correctAnswer = Number1 * Number2
Else
    Output = " / "
    correctAnswer = Number1 / Number2
End If
```

and finally, change to:

```
Console.WriteLine("The correct answer is " & correctAnswer)
```

Answer (score 1):

May I also suggest that you use a Select statement instead of consecutive If-Else statements.
Like this:

```
Dim Answer as Decimal

Select Case (Operation)
    Case 1
        Output = " + "
        Answer = Number1 + Number2
    Case 2
        Output = " - "
        Answer = Number1 - Number2
    Case 3
        Output = " * "
        Answer = Number1 * Number2
    Case Else
        Output = " / "
        Answer = Number1 / Number2
End Select
```